# In spacemacs how do I create a .spacemacs file while using emacs editing mode?

Tags: spacemacs

The spacemacs documentation for creating a spacemacs file describes how to do so when using the vi editing mode.

How do I do this if I'm using traditional emacs keybindings?

Comment: You might want to add a link to point to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

See this documentation page: https://www.spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#editing-styles

To switch to Emacs keybinding while in vi mode, use `SPC t E e` and for switching back to vi mode, use `M-m t E e`.

Note also that .spacemacs file is generated automatically - and inside there is a place where you can choose the keybinding to work with.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `~/.spacemacs` file is **[created](https://develop.spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#dotfile-installation)** for you on the first run of Spacemacs after installation.  To edit the file, Spacemacs has provided a few key sequences.

- <kbd>SPC f e d</kbd> should be used in vi mode.
- <kbd>M-m f e d</kbd> whould be used with traditional emacs keybindings.

Both of these keybindings call the function `spacemacs/find-dotfile` which will edit the dotfile in the current window.